# How do I display the cell number in Jupyter?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I would like to know how to display the cell number inside of a Jupyter notebook.

The motivation:
I am using `nbformat` to display information from a Jupyter notebook.

To retrieve text and image information I am currently relying on the `execution_count` value as in:

```
def select_cell(notebook, out_value):
    """
    returns the information of a cell
    """

    # Notebook formatting defintions
    if notebook["nbformat"] < 4:
        cell_all = list(notebook["worksheets"][0]["cells"])
        key_counter = 'prompt_number'
     else:
        cell_all = list(notebook["cells"])
        key_counter = 'execution_count'

     # Finding and returning the relevant cell
     for icell, cell in enumerate(cell_all):
        try: # Not all Cells have the `key_counts`
            if cell[key_counter] == out_value:
                return cell
        except:
            None

    return None
```

By `out_value` I am referring to the numerical value in the square brackets in a notebook on the left margin where is says "Out[out_value]:".
And `notebook = nbformat.read(file_notebook, 4)`.

I think that it would be better to have `select_cell` return the cell based on the actual cell value instead of looping on it. Especially since the `out_value` updates with each execution, where the cell value is constant.

Yes, one can count the cell numbers, but if it is a long notebook one could easily lose track.